# How to resolve the issue of NAs in distance matrix of a phyloseq object?

Tags: r, phyloseq

I'm unable to create cor_heatmap with phyloseq object in RStudio

I am trying to create a heatmap using cor_heatmap function to check the association of different taxa with different clinical variables, however I am getting this error:
Error in seriate.dist(dists, method = method) :
NAs not allowed in distance matrix x!
So I am stuck. I'm attaching the [figure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HAZGBSYvPpEH6BxNgSwUZjF4iA_Ea8Cd/view?usp=drive_link) below please someone kindly tell me what I'm doing wrong.
Here is the error: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HAZGBSYvPpEH6BxNgSwUZjF4iA_Ea8Cd/view?usp=drive_link
and here is the phyloseq object I am using:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xJlb7QD2igWh_6ld6i71-2b7Cvuiiwen/view?usp=drive_link